# Explain the number sequence and predict the next 6 numbers

Tags: number-sequence

Given the number sequence

> 0,1,4,9,0,1,9,1,4,2,1,3,0,4,1,5,4,6,9,7,0,9,9,a,4,?,?,?,?,?,?

the challenge is to

1. Determine the value represented by a
2. Predict the next 6 entries represented by ?

Note that

- This number sequence does not appear in the [online encyclopaedia of integer sequences](https://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C1%2C4%2C9%2C0%2C1%2C9%2C1%2C4&language=english&go=Search)
- If necessary hints will be added in due course.

Comment: rot13(Vf gurer n ernfba jul lbh'ir jevggra "n" naq abg "?")

Comment: term "a" was a big give away

Comment: Your title says 7 numbers, but everywhere else suggests 6.

Comment: @L.F. thanks for the comment.... will fix

Comment: @Prim3numbah - I guess the answer to that should be clear now...

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky -- Ahh yes. I always find it hard to find a balance between presenting an interesting challenge and making it too easy or too hard. Fair comment.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The rule of the sequence is:

> Write each square number in hexadecimal and reverse it.

Example & Answer:

> ```
> 0 = 0
> 1 = 1
> 4 = 4
> 9 = 9
> 16 = 0, 1
> 25 = 9, 1
> 36 = 4, 2
> 49 = 1, 3
> 64 = 0, 4
> 81 = 1, 5
> 100 = 4, 6
> 121 = 9, 7
> 144 = 0, 9
> 169 = 9, a (a represents 10 in hexadecimal)
> 196 = 4, c
> 225 = 1, e
> 256 = 0, 0, 1
> ```

Comment: Congratulations :-), nice explanation, well done!